# Java - Comparing unrelated objects with a custom order

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I want to sort a list that contains objects that are unrelated by providing a custom order. For example, the list I want to sort contains objects of the class Animal. An animal object has an object called type which may be a Cat, Mouse or Dog. I have a custom order Mouse < Cat < Dog. How can I achieve that the list containing animals is sorted with my custom order?
In particular, given the following code, I do not know how to implement the comparator. In addition this is a simplified example, I cannot modify the classes Dog, Cat, Mouse nor Animal.

```
// Cat and Mouse are similar 
public class Dog {
    ...
}

public class Animal {
    Object type;

    public Animal(Object aType) {
        type = aType;
    }

    // getter , setter etc.
}

public class Comparison {

       List<Animal> animals;

       public Comparison() {
          Dog dog1 = new Dog();
          Animal animal1 = new Animal(dog);
          animals.add(animal1);
          Cat cat1 = new Cat();
          Animal animal2 = new Animal(cat);
          animals.add(animal2);
          // add other elements of type dog, cat or mouse
          ....
          // sort the list with custom order: mouse<cat<dog
          Collections.sort(animals,intComparator());
       }

    private Comparator<Animal> intComparator() {
        return new Comparator<Animal>() {
          @Override
          public int compare(Animal first, Animal second) {
              return ???;
      }
    };
  }

}
```

One solution would be to manually check the class of type (via instanceof) and hard code the order in the comparator. However I have too many classes that can be contained in Animal (not only three as in this example), so this would yield a significant amount of if cases.

```
    private Comparator<Animal> intComparator() {
        return new Comparator<FXNode>() {
          @Override
          public int compare(Animal first, Animal second) {
              // if first is a mouse, return -1 because it is the 'smallest' object
              if (first.getType() instanceof Mouse) return -1;
              // if first is a cat and second a mouse, return 1 etc., a lot of if cases
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your example is bad and that you didn't actually do that, because it really is a poor conception. Maybe you should just reconsider your class hierarchy because I don't get the point of sorting unrelated objects.

Since you left a `Comparator<FXNode>` in your code, I guess you want to sort graphic components to process some method in a predefined order. If I understand what you want to do, this order is based on the runtime type of the FXNode. If that's the case, you could do that :

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<FXNode> {
    static Map<Class<? extends FXNode>,Integer> priorities = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        priorities.put(Node1.class,2);
        priorities.put(Node2.class,1);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(FXNode o1, FXNode o2) {
        return Integer.compare(priorities.get(o1.getClass()),priorities.get(o1.getClass()));
    }   
}
```

However, in a more general context I would advice you to compare only objects which a logically similar and consequentely share some attributes or methods.

Comment: Thanks, I have simplified this and used it (see my own answer). And yes, you are right in the assumption that this is a heavily simplified example. In my application the class hierarchy is a lot more complex and adding attributes to other classes just for aiding the comparison is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
enum Species { Cat, Dog, Mouse, ... };

class Animal {
  Species species;
};
```

Then for the comparator:

```
private Comparator<Animal> intComparator() {
  return new Comparator<FXNode>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Animal first, Animal second) {
      return first.species.compareTo(second.species);
    }
  }
}
```

The order comes from the `enum`.  You can attach attributes (number of legs, color, etc.) to `Species` values by making the declaration more complex.  See [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this completely depends on how you determine your custom ordering. For example, imagine if you had a `size` attribute in your `Animal` class, then you would use that attribute to compare the sizes in the `compare` method. If the factor which determines the ordering is not an attribute of the `Animal` class, then you would have to hardcode it the way you're doing it in your snippet.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any attribute that I can compare. The order is solely based on a logical order.

Comment: I don't have much context into your problem, but if there's an attribute (whatever it is), can't that be a part of the class. If it's  something that you can't easily put into the class, can you store it as an integer? Not sure that would change things a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance to what @DavidCourtinot posted, I will be using the following solution (which is a simplified version of his proposed one).

```
List<String> definedOrder =  Arrays.asList("Mouse", "Cat", "Dog");

private Comparator<Animal> intComparator() {
    return new Comparator<Animal>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Animal first, Animal second) {
          int firstIndex = 0;
          if (first.getType() instanceof Mouse) 
               firstIndex = definedOrder.getIndexOf("Mouse");
          // one if case per element in definedOrder
          ...

          int secondIndex = 0;
          if (second.getType() instanceof Mouse) 
               secondIndex = definedOrder.getIndexOf("Mouse);
          // again one if case per element

          return Integer.valueOf(firstIndex).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(secondIndex));

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a `List<Class>` and fill that List with all the classes you want to compare. Then use `indexOf()` to get two integers that you can use in your Comparator

Attaching some code showing the feasibility of that solution.

```
List<String> definedOrder =  Arrays.asList(Mouse.class, Cat.class, Dog.class);

private Comparator<Animal> intComparator() {
    return new Comparator<Animal>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Animal first, Animal second) {
            return Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(first.class)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(second.class)));
        }
    }
}
```